# when i try to set a variable that is already set the game crashes

Tags: c++, crash

I tryed looking up things that have to do with setting a variable that is already set causing a crash and I found nothing on-topic for this.

Rextblock is a user input number.  Returns random number between numbermax and 2 if textblock is equal to 1.

```
if ( textblock == 1 )
{
   int rand1 = rand() %(numbermax - 2) + 2;
   int textbox = rand1;
}
```

When I input 1 for textblock it crashes, i'm pretty sure this code is causing it.

```
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
srand(time(NULL));


int numbermax = 2;



while (while1 < 1)    
{   
cout << "input the number of the text block you wish to use, \n ";
int textblock;
cin >> textblock;

if ( textblock != 0 )
{

}

if ( textblock == 1 )
{
   int rand1 = rand() %(numbermax - 2) + 2;
   int textbox = rand1;
}

if (textblock == 2)
{

}

if (textblock == 2)
{

}


if( textblock == 0 )
{

}   

if ( textblock == 1 )
{
   cout << " \n error, try again \n";     
}
```

Comment: Do you use threads? Please provide some more informations. This part of code looks valid to me.

Comment: We need to see at least the declarations of numbermax and textblock and the exact error you get

Comment: Can you post some of the surrounding code as well?

Comment: @chris: go for an answer on that basis, that's the only idea I can get as well (from this block).

Comment: Is (numbermax - 2) being zero? because mod of zero would be undefined.surround by try and catch with logging.

Comment: @enthusiasticgeek, Try and catch won't do anything unless you explicitly check for it and throw an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly suspect that when you run it, `numbermax` is equal to 2. This would cause `numbermax - 2` to equal zero, and using modulus with a rhs of 0 invokes division by 0, which is undefined behaviour, hence the fair probability of a crash.

You should be making sure that it doesn't end up doing that via a check of `if (numbermax != 2)`.

Comment: thanks, posted more code, deleted all the cout/cin though to make it easier to read... ...0 and 1 are reserved for a couple other options, and by error i dont' get an error, it just crashes... so if i just add another option (i'm goign to do that anyway later...) it shoudl work fine? waht i'm doing is i'm setting numbermax to however many options i have so i can do this random thing here.

Comment: @user1743752, Yes, unless you change the value of `numbermax`, you'll run into the problem. If you're after selecting a number from 0 to numbermax, just use `rand() % numbermax` (assuming it isn't 0). If you need from 2 to `numbermax + 2`, use `rand() % numbermax + 2`.

Comment: no more crash and i found another error, i typed textbox instead of textblock... ...however sometimes it will come as 3 if i put rand() % numbermax + 2, subtracting one from numbermax first fixes it though, thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you mean:

```
textbox = rand1;
```

Your code sets local variable, which belongs to if block, and not external textbox variable. I don't see how this can crash the program though.